# CurrencyConverter in python . Error 'amounts' not defined , why ? . Also is there a shorter or more compact way of writing this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
```

I tried globalling amounts to fix my error but it didn't help

```
global amounts

c = CurrencyConverter()

currency = input('What ?')
currency = currency.split()
```

list of currency's to choose from , dictionary

```
currencys = {"pounds":"GBP" , "dollars":"USD" , "euros":"EUR"}
WCurrency = ' '
```

This is where it recognises what the sentence is

```
if 'what' in currency:
    next_word = currency[currency.index('what') + 1]
    if next_word == 'is':
```

long if statements I would like to be shortened if possible

```
        if 'pounds' in currency:
                amounts = currency[currency.index('pounds') - 1]
                WCurrency = currencys['pounds']
        if 'euros' in currency:
                amounts = currency[currency.index('euros') - 1]
                WCurrency = currencys['euros']

        if 'dollars' in currency:
                amounts = currency[currency.index('dollars') - 1]
                WCurrency = currencys['dollars']
        if 'in' in currency:
                next_word = currency[currency.index('in') + 1]
        if next_word == 'dollars':
                W2Currency = currencys['dollars']
        if next_word == 'pounds':
                W2Currency = currencys['pounds']
        if next_word == 'euros':
                W2Currency = currencys['euros']
```

This lets you input the sentence in a different format

```
if 'how' in currency:
    next_word = currency[currency.index('how') + 1]
    if next_word == 'many':
```

long if statements I would like to be shortened if possible

```
        if 'pounds' in currency:
            W2Currency = currencys['pounds']
        if 'euros' in currency:
            W2Currency = currencys['euros']
        if 'dollars' in currency:
            W2Currency = currencys['dollars']
        if 'is' in currency:
            next_word = currency[currency.index('is') + 1]
        if next_word == 'dollars':
            amounts = currency[currency.index('dollars') - 1]
            WCurrency = currencys['dollars']
        if next_word == 'pounds':
            amounts = currency[currency.index('pounds') - 1]
            WCurrency = currencys['pounds']
        if next_word == 'euros':
            amounts = currency[currency.index('euros') - 1]
            WCurrency = currencys['euros']








def convertCurrency(amount, currency, targertCurrency):

    try:
        return c.convert(amount , currency , targertCurrency)
    except:
        print('Invalid currency or amounts!')


print(convertCurrency(amounts, str(WCurrency), str(W2Currency)))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain what your program is trying to do. I know it seems obvious to you, but it's not obvious to us. Consider: if your code worked, we could maybe read it and work out what it does. But you are presenting us with code that doesn't do what you want, so no amount of reading it well tell us what it is supposed to do, because it doesn't do it.

Comment: Your right sorry , you are supposed to input a string e.g : 'What is 10 pounds in dollars' and it will identify the amount : '10' the base currency : 'pounds' and the currency you are trying to find out : 'dollars'.

Comment: Then if you say 'How many pounds in 10 dollars' it should identify the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `elif` this prevents dollars from being recognized again. Also it's good practice. i.e.

```
    if 'pounds' in currency:
            amounts = currency[currency.index('pounds') - 1]
            WCurrency = currencys['pounds']
    elif 'euros' in currency:
            amounts = currency[currency.index('euros') - 1]
            WCurrency = currencys['euros']

    elif 'dollars' in currency:
            amounts = currency[currency.index('dollars') - 1]
            WCurrency = currencys['dollars']
    elif 'in' in currency:
            next_word = currency[currency.index('in') + 1]
    elif next_word == 'dollars':
            W2Currency = currencys['dollars']
    elif next_word == 'pounds':
            W2Currency = currencys['pounds']
    elif next_word == 'euros':
            W2Currency = currencys['euros']
```

this means that if `dollars` and `pounds` are in the sentance it will recognise the first one. Alas this code is very messy and I would suggest using a `for` loop. i.e

```
for word in sentance:
    if word is in [list, of, currencies] and isdigit(sentance(word.index() - 1)):
        currency = word
```

and so on...